# Relabeling pod name in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I'm running Prometheus-Operator and using Kubernetes Service-Discovery for monitoring all the running pods.
I have a few pods with name `myapp-frontend-node-1q2ewq3q4e32`. How do I create a relabel configuration that will change the name of the pods from the above to something like `myapp-frontend-node`?

Comment: as long as it is a deployment which is your case, you can't get rid of the has in the end

Comment: I cannot configure prometheus to relabel the name?

Comment: You want to relabel those for the final metric readability?

Comment: Yes, so eventually when I query in Prometheus for `kube_pod_info` I will see `pod=myapp-frontend`

Comment: The only thing I was able to find is [Prometheus relabeling tricks](https://medium.com/quiq-blog/prometheus-relabeling-tricks-6ae62c56cbda), hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following relabeling config should drop the last part after `-` from `pod` label:

```yaml
- source_labels: [pod]
  regex: "(.*)-[^-]+"
  target_label: pod
```

You can debug this relabeling rule [here](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/target-relabel-debug).

The last part of the `pod` label can be also removed at query time with the help of [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function:

```
label_replace(some_metric, "pod", "$1", "pod", "(.*)-[^-]+")
```